# Does automerge modify server version in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I just did a long overdue "Get Latest Version" on a project I have not worked on in a while. I was prompted to automerge and I accepted. I had couple files checked out before the automerge, but they are no longer checked out. Does this mean that the server version now has some of my changes even though I never did a check in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No automerge does not check the merged files in. Can you do a "tf status" on the files in question to see their statuses? Did you lose any changes in these files? If the changes are still there (but the files are not checked out) you can try "tf edit" the files again. You can also "tf history" on the files to see their changes on server.